# Move the title of my SharePoint 2013 site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, move, title

In yellow, the title of my SharePoint site.

I would like to move it to the right. How can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled [publishing features](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-publishing-features-479677a6-8b33-4ac7-907d-071c1c7e4518), then you could upload your own CSS file to your site and then specify that it be used on your site via the Alternate CSS URL option in Site settings > Master page

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
#pageTitle{
    text-align:right
    }
```

You could add this css code to master page,or you could use @Callum's way.
[image]